# Is there something like #ifdef for methods in java?

Tags: java

Is there something in java that would allow me to stop a method from being compiled into a program depending on a value? Something like:

```
#ifdef CLIENT
public void drawToScreen() {

}
#endif

#ifdef SERVER
public void sendPacketToClient() {

}
#endif
```

If you had two versions of a program, one client and one server, how could you do this? Is there a way to do it with classes too?

Comment: No. This feels very unmaintainable.

Comment: No, and even if you could, why would you?

Comment: No, there isn't (with just java). In your specific example, I would develop two different applications, one as server, another as client. Making both server and client in one application where methods are conditionally declared would make everything a lot confusing to me

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/schaefa/archive/2005/01/how_to_do_condi.html.

Comment: You can control compilation at the class level, but not the method level.

Comment: @BackSlash Good idea, I was just wondering :)

Comment: Even in C this is not strictly speaking "compiled", since it is part of preprocessing. You can use any preprocessor macro or script to generate a source depending on certain variables. However for this use-case your approach does not seem recommendable as other comments mention.

Comment: There isn't, but there are many ways to achieve the same; one way is to implement an interface and use DI.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The JVM only loads and compiles to native code methods you actually use, so this is done for you dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Not very easily. All of the other comments say that this is impossible, but it actually **is** possible

You *can* use a [bytecode manipulation library](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) if you really wanted to. As the JavaAssist website says:

> Javassist (Java Programming Assistant) makes Java bytecode manipulation simple. It is a class library for editing bytecodes in Java; it enables Java programs to define a new class at runtime and to modify a class file when the JVM loads it.

But the biggest question is what's the point? It's really too much work and not very useful.